# Timeout POSTing 100ish KB to Azure app service MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, post

I'm posting to an MVC azure app service and on the larger requests (100-150KB+) they are timing out before hitting any of my code.

If I look in the log streams (application or web server) I don't see the requests hitting the server
If I attach the remote debugger to the process, it never hits the first line of code in the controller

If I run the webapp locally in IIS express and post to it, I have no issue and it goes through right away.

The request is just XML data (using application/xml) for the type.

The controller and routing is pretty bare bones

Routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
    //defaults: new {}
);
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public UpdateRepairOrderResponse Post()
{
    int ix = 0; //doesn't even hit this
}
```

Test App using RestSharp

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://AZUREURL/Post");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
        request.AddParameter("application/xml", "<105kb of xml data here>", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like this might be an issue for others using client certificates: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from Azure support. I am using client certificate authentication and it looks to be an issue there with requests above a certain size (around 100KB)

From support:

> To confirm, this issue occurs with client authentication turned on? If
>   so this is currently a known issue. The current workaround is to
>   either establish a connection with a smaller payload or use the
>   existing connection to post the new payload.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you shown:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://AZUREURL/Post");
```

but the url should be :

```
"https://AZUREURL/ControllerName".
```

not sure if this is a typo when you pasted it on SO.

Comment: I just stripped out the URL but i am using https://azureURL/Controller/Post in the test

Comment: Post in the url shouldn't be needed. Maybe there's a problem with https ? does http works?

Comment: Post is just the action on the controller. Works fine locally and on smaller requests (typical size is probably 10KB)